# SimpleDateFormat WeekDayNumber

Tags: android, simpledateformat

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public String WeekDayNumber(){
    long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("c");
    return df.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

This gives me weekday name of the date.
I want to get weekdaynumber like 
"0" for sunday, "1" for monday ... "6" for saturday as string.
I've read the [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but stand-alone day of week is not so close.
I don't want to write a function like replace "Mon" to "1" because of various device locale.

How can I get the week day number of the date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`:

```
      long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
      System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Calendar class in a Java action.

Some sample code:

```
SimpleDateFormat regularDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy");
Date date = regularDateFormat.parse("08:04:2010");
System.out.println("date: " + date.toString());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.println("day of week: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

This will produce the following output:

date: Thu Apr 08 00:00:00 CEST 2010
day of week: 5

You could easily build a java action that takes a date as input and returns the day numb